# input masking to show single character place - " _ _ _ "

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, masking

i'm wondering is there any possiblity to mask input to be showing something like this -> " _ _ _ _ _ _ " where single " _ " is a place to type character.

So the final result when user is typing should look similar to this " t y p _ _ _  "

Thanks for help!

-- 
i tryied to do this by maskedinput, but when i allow to type special characters and whitespace in regex ([0-9a-zA-ąłóżźćę ?]*/) it does not work well.

Comment: Did you search the internet for jQuery masked input?

Comment: Can you please show your actual maskedinput config (and clarify which if any plugin you are using)? Please elaborate on "does not work well".

Comment: Use the mask definition as described in [here](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/issues/15)

Answer (score 0):

Well, just did a quick search for "mask input jquery plugin" in Google and this is what it came up first result [masked-input-plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). Seems like that is what you're looking for.

**EDIT:**

If you're indeed using this plugin then this should work:

```
$input.mask('999999');
```

Comment: This is almost definitely the plugin that the OP says he was using.

Comment: Well, that's why I updated the answer. I must've skiped that part or OP edited the question.

Comment: Ok might be since OP did not put it as an update, I did not knew. But anyways your edit will only allow numbers to be typed not alphabetic characters. Check this out [link](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo)